# NET8 MAUI and deploy for testing to a real device

Tags: c#, ios, maui

I'm creating an application with `NET8` `MAUI` and now I want to test the application on my real iPhone. My iMac is connected to the Visual Studio on the Windows machine and I can test the application on an iPhone simulator.

When I try to deploy the same app to my iPhone, I get this error:

> clang++ exited with code 1: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_UMPConsentForm", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in registrar.o   "*OBJC_CLASS*$_UMPConsentInformation", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in registrar.o   "*OBJC_CLASS*$_UMPDebugSettings", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in registrar.o   "*OBJC_CLASS*$_UMPRequestParameters", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in registrar.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
> 1 (use -v to see invocation)  LanguageInUse   C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets 1559

[image]

The phone is connected to the iMac but I tried also to deploy with WiFi with the same result. I tried to deploy as *Debug* or *Release*.

### Update

I noticed in the log of the build, those lines. I'm not sure they are really related to the issue.

> 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(746,3):
> warning MT7091: The framework
> C:/Users/enric/.nuget/packages/xamarin.firebase.ios.core/8.10.0.3/lib/net6.0-ios15.4/Firebase.Core.resources/GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework/ios-arm64/GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework
> is a framework of static libraries, and will not be copied to the app.
> 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(746,3):
> warning MT7091: The framework
> C:/Users/enric/AppData/Local/XamarinBuildDownloadCache/FAdM-8.13.0/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleMobileAds.framework
> is a framework of static libraries, and will not be copied to the app.
> 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(746,3):
> warning MT7091: The framework
> C:/Users/enric/AppData/Local/XamarinBuildDownloadCache/GAppM-8.9.1/GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework
> is a framework of static libraries, and will not be copied to the app.
> 2>"$(xcrun -find bitcode_strip)"
> C:/Users/enric/AppData/Local/XamarinBuildDownloadCache/GAppM-8.9.1/GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement
> -r -o C:/Users/enric/AppData/Local/XamarinBuildDownloadCache/GAppM-8.9.1/GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement
> 2>"$(xcrun -find bitcode_strip)"
> C:/Users/enric/AppData/Local/XamarinBuildDownloadCache/FAdM-8.13.0/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds
> -r -o C:/Users/enric/AppData/Local/XamarinBuildDownloadCache/FAdM-8.13.0/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds

Comment: Did you look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/linking?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs

Comment: Did you use any third party nuget? Does it happen if you create a default Maui project?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT with a simple project is working fine. I think the issue is related to a Google Ads component. Here the issue on GitHub https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob/issues/60

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you that it may relate to the Google ads plugin. You may follow up the issue on GitHub. Thanks for your sharing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was coming from the component [MauiMTAdmob](https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob) by Marco Troncone. The issue was that for some reason, the `Xamarin.Google.iOS.UserMessagingPlatform` was required.

After 2 days, Marco fixed the issue and the new version of the NuGet package is fixed.